# How to run code on your site from different programming languages?

Tags: javascript, web-applications

Is there a way i can design a code editor that would allow users to write, say, small java programs in the site and on the server it's somehow compiled and the results are returned?

Comment: Yes you can. You can simply send the imputed code though a parser on the server and return the resulting output/file. For example, in PHP, you can use the `exec()` function to execute a commandline function.

Comment: Like [ideone](http://ideone.com/)?

Comment: Not if you care about keeping your server secure.